# Can't get index of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the index of the current item `<p>` but I have nothing. I get only the index of the first element
http://jsfiddle.net/T4uVG/7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index of `<p>` element should be taken with:

```
$(this).parent().index();
```

since `this` refers to child `<span>` element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/T4uVG/8/